# Best method for using stored procedures and table valued functions in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, ado.net, asp.net-core-5.0

We are developing a razor application with VueJS on the frontend and razor / ASP.NET Core 5 on the backend. VueJS accesses the data via post (ajax) requests which we are handling using page handlers in the page models.

I have integrated Entity Framework and done a few queries for practice however I am realizing Entity Framework is not my answer. All of my SQL queries are saved as table valued functions in SQL Server and the update / insert / delete operations are done using stored procedures in SQL Server.

We have a SQL programmer so he just does everything server-side to keep things simple and just gives us function / procedure names and parameters.

I like this approach and we used this in our application when it was VBA in Excel using ADO and recordsets but now that we are using ASP.NET Core in a web setting so I am learning Entity Framework. However EF requires me to maintain models and that seems unnecessarily complicated as my SQL results are generated from procedures / functions.

Really I just need to run these procedures / functions and return the results as a json data array in the POST request.

What would be the best option for this in regards to performance and simplicity (hopefully they can go hand in hand)? A simple code example would also be helpful to get the ball rolling.

As for other questions on StackOverflow I have seen one question which is similar that says dapper is great for stored procedures but does not indicate if table valued functions are allowable.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Entity Framework Core also allows us to execute raw SQL query to make use of existing stored procedure. For more information about executing raw SQL queries with Entity Framework Core, you can check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Besides, if you want to implement it with ADO.NET approach, you can try to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` that provides the data provider for Microsoft SQL Server.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

Comment: I need to be able to do both stores procedures and table valued functions. Can I do those both but also not have to worry about creating models? Or can I db scaffold those similar to the database tables? It’s just so time consuming setting up models for ever procedure.

Comment: EF Core supports mapping a queryable function to a table-valued function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function

Comment: No model class is required ? If there is no context how does this iqueryable know the connection details for the db? I’ll look into this approach more. EF I have read has a lot of overhead for what I am doing. Ado.net might be better but again it looks like ado.net uses model classes as well. Anyway to do without? Might solve my question/problem